# How do I sort a table while keeping a record of the original positions?

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

I have a Lua table of integers which I sort in ascending order. Later on, my script need to take the index of the smallest number (that is, the position it was on originally, before sorting), try something, then move on to the index of the second smallest number, try something, etc. until the end of the sorted list.

My problem is that I obviously lose the original positions (or indexes) of my original table when I sort it. Is there a way, maybe with a nested table holding both numbers and indexes, to keep a record of the original indexes, and then perform a sort on the integers?

To make the question a little bit clearer:

> Original table: 4 6 2
>
> Sorted table: 2 4 6
>
> In this sorted table, I need to know that 2 was at the position 3
>   before sorting, that 4 was at position 1, and that 6 was at position
>   2.

Comment: Yes, a nested table can do that for you as can keeping a second table (assuming your values are guaranteed unique).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, my values are guarantied unique. Do you have an idea how to implement this efficiently? I'm not familiar with nesting in lua, and have a hard time with the syntax...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following (untested code written in answer box) should work regardless of uniqueness (though lua table sorting isn't stable so you can't guarantee which of equal elements will be sorted first in case that matters):

```
local origtab = {4, 6, 2}
local sorttab = {}
for i,v in ipairs(origtab) do
    sorttab[i] = {index = i, value = v}
end
table.sort(sorttab, function(a, b) return a.value < b.value end)
for i,t in ipairs(sorttab) do
    -- t.index is original index
    -- t.value is value
end
```

Comment: This looks like a really good answer! when testing, though, my interpreter finds an error at line "table.sort(sorttab, function(a, b) a.value < b.value end)". The error says "'=' expected near '<'". Any idea what could cause this? Cheers!

Comment: I missed a `return` in the comp function. Try that.

Answer (score 3):

If all of your values are guaranteed to be unique, then this is pretty simple.

```
local function remember_sort(t)
  local map = {}
  for i=1, #t do map[t[i]] = i end
  table.sort(t)
  return map -- map of values to old indices
end

local t = {4, 6, 2}
local r = remember_sort(t)

for k, v in pairs(r) do print(k, v) end
```

```
2       3
4       1
6       2
```